# spaghetti code - how to fix my db calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My db calls are like this:

```
orders_pending_acceptance = Order.joins(:notifications).includes(:timestamps)
    .where(shopper_status: 'shopper_pending_acceptance')
    .where("notifications.created_at > ?", now - 10.minutes)
    .select { |order| order.time_calculator
      .latest_shopper_assignment_time < order.timestamps
      .where(name: 'shopper_pending_acceptance').value }
```

and it looks ugly, not speaking about hound issues. How to fix it? Could you please suggest different approach?

Comment: You can use scopes for all your where conditions. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: `now - 10.minutes` = `10.minutes.ago`